# addTarget for Multiple Buttons Issue

Tags: ios, swift3, selector, addtarget

```
            for (index,phoneNum) in temp_arr_phoneNum.enumerated()
            {
               if temp_arr_msgType[index] == "3"
               {
                let btnimage : UIButton = UIButton()

                btnimage.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"VideoIConDefault"), for: .normal)
                btnimage.tag = index
                btnimage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                btnimage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                containerView.addSubview(btnimage)
                btnimage.addTarget(self, action: 
                 #selector(self.tapDetected(_:)), for:UIControlEvents(rawValue: 0))
                arrayForBtnViews.append(btnimage)
               }
          }
       func tapDetected(_ sender: UIButton)
       {
       }
```

Only for the first button Action Target method is working......Other buttons are not performing clicked actions...(controlEvents,,, I tried for .touchUpInside also).....Button frames have been set through  auto layout constraints programatically in other methods.

Comment: Is if temp_arr_msgType[index] == "3", true for multiple cases? What is the frame of containerView? Do containerView.clipsToBounds = true and check whether your other buttons are still visible.

Comment: It is true for multiple cases,,,,ContainerView Frame is dynamically changed,,,It is inside scrollView... I am able to see Mutiple buttons on the screen. But action is working for first button only...I didnot use clipsToBounds = true.(it is unchecked in storyboard for containerview...Is it required?

Comment: If you want to make sure that the buttons can receive events, check the cliptosubviews property on containerView. This will clip all subviews(buttons in your case) where subview does not fit inside container frame.

Comment: Checked to ClipsToBounds of ContainerView is giving InCorrect or Unexpected UI on Screen...

Comment: So, I guess you can see the problem now. Your UIButtons are out of bounds from your container view and hence they can not receive touch events.

Comment: After clipToSubviews, can you still see the buttons?

Comment: Thank You So much Puneet Sharma,, Yes You are correct. They are out of Container View.The problem is in the storyBoard, One constraint was wrong in Landscape mode. Now working fine...

Comment: Glad to help!!!